# Tortoise SVN´s commit ignores new files

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, commit

Everytime I add a new file to my project a need to "add" this file by Tortoise SVN.

Is there any way to get theses files directly when I commit my branch?

Thanks!

Comment: Use VisualSVN in VisualStudio, when you here use any add command in VS, the file is added to the WC, so tat you can commit it.

Answer (score 3):

No. And it's "by design" solution: not every new file in your WC have to be part of repository and not every not versioned artifact can be ignored

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice little checkbox at the bottom of the commit dialog:

[image]

If you check that box, you will see all new (and unversioned) files in the commit dialog. If you want to add them to the commit, you can simply check those files too.